# Run helm in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I have added helm as podtemplate in value.yaml file

```
 podTemplates: 
    helm: |
      - name: helm
        label: jenkins-helm
        serviceAccount: jenkins
        containers:
          - name: helm
            image: lachlanevenson/k8s-helm:v3.1.1
            command: "/bin/sh -c"
            args: "cat"
            ttyEnabled: true
            privileged: true
            resourceRequestCpu: "400m"
            resourceRequestMemory: "512Mi"
            resourceLimitCpu: "1"
            resourceLimitMemory: "1024Mi"
```

so i want to run helm in pipeline as

```
     steps {
            container('helm') {
                sh "helm upgrade --install --force  ./helm"
            }
        }
```

but i got error

```
       /home/jenkins/workspace/coverwhale@tmp/durable-4d1fbfd5/script.sh: 1: /home/jenkins/workspace/coverwhale@tmp/durable-4d1fbfd5/script.sh: helm: not found
```

**Version of Helm and Kubernetes**:

Helm Version:

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.2", GitCommit:"167aac70832d3a384f65f9745335e9fb40169dc2", GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.15.7"}
```

Kubernetes Version:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:28:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:20:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**Which version of the chart**:

**What happened**:
/home/jenkins/workspace/coverwhale@tmp/durable-4d1fbfd5/script.sh: 1: /home/jenkins/workspace/coverwhale@tmp/durable-4d1fbfd5/script.sh: helm: not found

**What you expected to happen**:
run helm chart

pipeline code

```
pipeline {

agent any

stages {

         stage('Initialize Docker'){
             steps {
                  script {
                       def docker = tool 'whaledocker'
                       echo "${docker}"
                       echo "${env.PATH}"
                       env.PATH = "${docker}/bin:${env.PATH}"
                       echo "${env.PATH}"
                  }
             }
        }
    
        stage('Checkout Source') {

             steps {
                 git url:'https://github.com/alialrabi/laravel-example.git', branch: 'uat', credentialsId: 'github'
             }
        }

        stage("Build image") {
      
            steps {
                 script {
                   myapp = docker.build("alialrabi/coverwhale:${env.BUILD_ID}")
                 }
            }
        }
    
 
        stage("Run Test") {
      
            steps {
                 script {
                      docker.image("alialrabi/coverwhale:${env.BUILD_ID}").inside {
                     //   sh 'composer install'  
                      //  sh 'php artisan test'
                      }
                 }
            }
        }
    

        stage("Push image") {
        
             steps {
                
                 script {
                     docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'dockerhub') {
                          myapp.push("latest")
                          myapp.push("${env.BUILD_ID}")
                     }
                 }
             }
        }

        stage('Deploy Uat') {
            
 
            steps {
                 script {
                echo "Done Uat"
                  sh "helm upgrade --install --force"
             }
            }
        }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what is your agent in pipeline script?

Comment: @NisargShah I have updated post with pipeline code

Comment: Check if helm is installed in Jenkins Server

Comment: yes,It seem it's not installed, but i don't know a way to install helm in jenkins node

Comment: Can you check whether you are able to manually access `helm` command inside jenkins workspace i.e. `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace` ? Just try running `helm version` command inside the given path. And if you are not able to access, then try accessing with `sudo`.

Comment: I installed jenkins using helm chart,but elm not in installed

Comment: If you want to run helm commands through jenkinsfile, then helm should be installed on the container/machine where jenkins is installed.

Comment: So,How to install helm in jenkins pod?

Comment: That will depend on how you installed jenkins itself. You mentioned you installed Jenkins via a chart so you might be able to edit the requirements.txt/dockerfile to install helm with the image.

Comment: Agreed with Krishna. It depends on how you installed jenkins. Maybe you can edit requirements.txt or dockerfile using which you can install helm in jenkins. Is it necessary to install jenkins using helm chart?

Comment: I have installed jenkins using helm chart, helm install jenkins jenkins/jenkins -f values.yaml

Comment: I know this type of use case of docker : 
We can give your jenkins access to docker socket either by giving it the unix socket using a bind mount. For example : `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):$(which docker) ubuntu bash`

Similarly, can you do with helm chart? I do not have experience with that so I don't know where the path of socket is and all.

Comment: @Ali-Alrabi Have you tried using the above comment's approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by add containerTemplate to agent.

```
  stage('Deploy dev') {
            
         agent {
           kubernetes {
                 containerTemplate {
                   name 'helm'
                   image 'lachlanevenson/k8s-helm:v3.1.1'
                   ttyEnabled true
                   command 'cat'
              }
            }
         }
            
            steps {
               container('helm') { 
                 sh "helm upgrade full-cover ./helm"
               }    
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can install helm on the instance as well in which you are running your jenkins pipeline

```
stage("helm install"){
steps{
    echo "Helm install"      
    sh 'curl -o kubectl https://amazon-eks.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.18.9/2020-11-02/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl'       
    sh 'curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" '
    sh 'sudo cp kubectl /usr/bin' 
    sh 'sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/kubectl'
    sh 'wget https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.6.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz'
    sh 'ls -a'
    sh 'tar -xvzf helm-v3.6.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz'
    sh 'sudo cp linux-amd64/helm /usr/bin'
  }
}
```