# How to trigger helm from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, pipeline

I am new to DevOps and have the below scenario to handle.

Environment:-

Host is running on MacOS.
A Kubernete cluster running on Minikube was installed on this MacOS. This Minikube cluster has 2 environments(namespaces) - Development and Production.
Each namespace will have a MySQL database deployed.

The Docker host service is also running on the MacOS host.  Helm and kubectl clients are installed on the MacOS host.

Jenkins will be used for building the CI and CD process and was setup in a pod within the jenkins namespace on the Minikube.

Objective:-
I need to build a CICD pipeline which consist of a NodeJS application that will be embedded in a docker image. This docker image will be deployed as a pod.  It will connect to a database in the development environment to  retrieve a text string from a MySQL database which will be displayed in the web browser. Upon successful testing, the image will be deployed to the Production namspace.

Pipeline workflow:-

1. Jenkins will retrieve the code for the NodeJS application from GitHub.
2. Jenkins will build the Docker image by creating a container inside a pod in the jenkins namespace with the NodeJS application embedded via a DockerFile.
3. The image will be pushed to a repository (eg, DockerHub).
4. Jenkins will then pull the image from DockerHub and deploy to the development environment(dev namespace)  using Helm.
5. A series of test will then be conducted.
6. Once successful, the same image will then be deployed to the(production namespace) using Helm.

I got the below pipeline up till step 3 working and was stucked at step 4.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  
  environment {
        DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS = credentials('DOCKERHUB_LOGIN')
  }
  
  tools {nodejs "nodejs"}

  parameters {
    gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'main', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH'
  }
  
  stages {
    stage('Clone Code Repository') {
      steps {
        git branch: "${params.BRANCH}", url: 'https://github.com/dkelim1/nodejs-app.git'
      }
    }
    
    stage('Install NPM application') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm install'
      }
    }
    
    
    stage('Download docker binary') {
        steps{
            script {
                    def dockerHome = tool 'docker'
                    env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"           
            }
        }
    }    
    

    stage('Docker Build and Tag') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withServer('tcp://192.168.59.102:2376', 'DOCKERHOST_CRED'){
                sh 'docker build -t dkelim1/nodejs-app .' 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    stage('DockerHub Login') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withServer('tcp://192.168.59.102:2376', 'DOCKERHOST_CRED'){
                sh 'echo $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW | docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR --password-stdin'     
                }
            }    
        }
    }

    stage('Push Image to DockerHub') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withServer('tcp://192.168.59.102:2376', 'DOCKERHOST_CRED'){
                sh 'docker push dkelim1/nodejs-app:latest' 
                }
            }    
        }
    }


    stage('Logout from DockerHub') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withServer('tcp://192.168.59.102:2376', 'DOCKERHOST_CRED'){
                sh 'docker logout' 
                }
            }    
        }
    }
    
  }    
}
```

I am trying to achieve the below but did not know how.  Would appreciate if anyone can advise how do I achieve it.

1. How to trigger helm from within the pipeline to perform the deployments? Googled around and watched a couple of DevOps videos but none seems to be answering to my needs.
2. For step number 2, instead of building the docker image as a pod in the jenkins namespace, how can I build it as a pod in the dev namespace instead?

I goggled and tried the proposed solution within the below link but it did not help.

[Run helm in jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66399589/run-helm-in-jenkins-pipeline)

```
    name: "workspace-volume"

Running on testpipeline-1-0xk9b-90pm8-31qgv in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/testpipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ helm list -A
Error: list: failed to list: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jenkins:default" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: 1. You can add another stage to the pipeline to perform the deployment with Helm. This can done with the Jenkins Pipeline library for Helm, or otherwise. The Helm chart should reference the image you pushed to the registry, and you can pass the tag as a parameter. 2. You would probably need to modify the `agent` directive for that.

Comment: Looks like your system:serviceaccount:jenkins:default does not have the required permissions. You may need to create proper clusterrole/clusterrolebindings.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the immediate error, which is a permission error, you will need to grant permission to the `jenkins` user to read secrets (fair warning, this can be a security issue if your Jenkins is not locked down). Manifests like the below will set up a role with those permissions and grant it to Jenkins (you might need to change the `subjects` list to match your installation).

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
 name: jenkins-read-secrets-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
 name: jenkins-read-secrets-binding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: jenkins
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: jenkins
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
roleRef:
 kind: ClusterRole
 name: jenkins-read-secrets-role
 apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

As for the target namespace, Helm can deploy into any given namespace, but you may need additional permissions set up to permit your Jenkins user to do so.